# angular2 - How to I use md-error with a custom validator

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

How to I use md-error with a custom validator?  Required works..great! but what about my custom validator?

```
<md-input-container>
     <input mdInput formControlName="etr" >

     <md-error *ngIf="WHAT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!">
               ETR must be >=0 or <1
     </md-error>
     <md-error *ngIf="myForm.controls['etr'].hasError('required')">
            <strong>required</strong>
     </md-error>


 </md-input-container>
```

Here is my type script:

```
     this.myForm = fb.group({
         etr: [,[Validators.required,ModelValidators.validEtr]],

     })
```

I does show the error underline but how do I show the message?

I tried this but did not work:

```
    *ngIf="myForm.controls['etr'].hasError('validEtr')"
```

Below is my validator.ts file

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class ModelValidators{

static validEtr(control: FormControl){
        var valid: any;
        valid=null;
        if (control.value>=0 && control.value<1){
            valid = true;
        }
        return valid ? null : { validLambda: true };

    }
}
```

Comment: please post code about `ModelValidators.validEtr`?

Comment: I added the validator.ts file..it works..as the form is disabled until valid input but I just cant show the error message.  I get a red line though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validLambda` is the error type returned from your custom validator when validate failed.

so the solution is as below:

```
*ngIf="myForm.controls['etr'].hasError('validLambda')"
```

Comment: It worked but what if I had multiple custom?  How could I tell the difference?

Comment: @Tampa do you mean multiple custom validator on single element? you can distinct them by the error type returned from custom validators. hope I have got what you meant. :-)